# How to clear message archive on ejabberd server? (I am the server admin)

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

How do I clear all message archives on a fresh ejabberd installation? I accidentally enabled mod_mam and set it to default: always, but now I'm willing to delete message archives (mod_mam is already set to "never")

Tried nothing

Answer (score 2):

> How do I clear all message archives on a fresh ejabberd installation?

See:

```
$ ejabberdctl help delete_old_mam_messages
  Command Name: delete_old_mam_messages
  Arguments: type::binary
             days::integer
  Returns: res::rescode
  Tags:  purge
  Description:  Delete MAM messages older than DAYS
 Valid message TYPEs: "chat", "groupchat", "all".

$ ejabberdctl delete_old_mam_messages all 0
$
```